# Cannot overwrite CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to embedded some styles into my website, however, the right style didn't show up, and I don't know why.

My code is here:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
#bd { font-family: 'Neuton', serif;  color:#646464; font-size:16px; line-height:21px; font-weight:200;}
...
</head>

<body>
...
<div class="container" id="bd">
    I want to use the font "Neuton' here. But I fail to do it..
</div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me with this :(?

**********update*********

I still can't find the reason, let me give more context:
I'm practicing using HTML/CSS to write a portfolio, and here is all of my code:

```
<head>
<title> XXXXX </title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:200" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
            body { padding-top: 40px;}

            #bd { font-family: 'Neuton', serif;  color:#646464; font-size:16px; line-height:21px; font-weight:200;}

            #bd a { 
                text-decoration:  none;     
                border-bottom: 1px dotted; 
                color:#646464;
            }
            #bd a:hover { text-decoration:  none; border-bottom: 1px dotted; color:#646464; background-color:#c0f4ff; }
            h1 { 
                font-family: 'Terminal Dosis', sans-serif;  
                color:#646464; 
                padding:0px; 
                margin-top:-14px; 
                margin-bottom:0px; 
                font-weight:300; 
                font-size:15px;
            }
            #sections { font-family: 'Terminal Dosis', sans-serif;  color:#7a7a7a; padding:0px; font-weight:300; font-size:80%; line-height:15px;}

            #name    { font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;   font-size:20px; color:#7a7a7a; padding-bottom:7px;}

            .dashbar { border-top: 1px dashed #bbbbbb; margin-bottom: 35px; margin-top:00px; }
            #active { background-color:#c0f4ff; color:#646464; width:100%;}
            #navlist li { color:#7a7a7a; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:15px; display: inline;
                list-style-type: none; float:right; padding-left:74px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:0px; }
            a { text-decoration:  none; color:#7a7a7a;  }
            a:hover {color:#646464; text-decoration:  none; background-color:#c0f4ff;  } /*color:: the color displayed when you mouse over the link*/
            a:visited { text-decoration:  none;  ;}/* mouse over link */
            a:active {  background-color:#c0f4ff; color:#646464; } /*the one that is activated */

    </style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4" id="name">My Name</div>
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li>
                <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="active" href="index.html">HOME</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dashbar"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span-one-third" id="bd">
                <!-- content-->
                <h1>ABOUT</h1>
                ***I want to use the font Neuton Here***
            </div>

            <div class="span10" style="margin-left: 30px;">
                <!-- put an image here -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Did you *close* that `<style>` tag?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but where are you getting the font from?  Is it installed on your computer? If not, are you using @font-face?

Comment: OK, so the `Neuton` font doesn't show up... Do you at least get the `serif`, and the other styles, or does the CSS fail altogether?

Comment: It's true this is a stupid question...
1. I did close <style> tag
2. I didn't use @font-face, sorry, I'm just a CSS beginner, I want to overwrite some of the styles bootstrap provides, and I directly embedded my CSS style in the <head> 

To Mr Lister:
Yes, it did show up the serif font!

Comment: I found a really stupid mistake, thanks for all! 

I used the comment symbol "//" in the code, cause I thought the comment symbols should be the same as C (/* */), but actually there is not single line comment here...

How stupid I am...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about that bootstraper , however I think you should import the fonts, I used google api. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/RWu3x/)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you missed out `</style>` tag. Your code doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

for some point you should clear the browsing history for css to work if the css code has been change

Answer (score 0):

There may be two problems:

1. Did you close that `<style>` tag? (`</style>`)
2. Where are you getting that font from? Is it installed on your computer? If not you need to use [`@font face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face).

If you have closed the `<style>` tag and/or used [`@font face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face), you better include it in your code, there will be a lot of people telling you to do that.

Thanks for reading!